# PowerPoint - Auto-update slide data from linked raw data file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to have a PowerPoint slide automatically link/sync with data from an Excel spreadsheet (or any other type raw data format)?

We've found a way to copy & paste excel data into PowerPoint, and then edit that data as an Excel Object. However, the original Excel spreadsheet is not updating when editing from PowerPoint.  Also, if the original Excel spreadsheet is updated outside of PowerPoint, the changes are not shown in Powerpoint.

Is there a way to sync a raw data file with PowerPoint so that the data updates in PowerPoint whenever the raw data file is updated?

We are using Microsoft Office 2011 for Mac.

After including an Excel object into PowerPoint, once I right click on the Excel object, this is the menu presented:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have Microsoft Office 2013 for Windows, but I'm assuming the directions are the same.

When you paste the excel spreadsheet or selection into PowerPoint, you need to use Home > Paste > Paste Special.  Select the Paste Link radio button.  Then select "Microsoft Excel Binary Worksheet Object" and OK. This will paste the excel spreadsheet and link it to the original.

[Paste special dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXWeK.jpg)

Now, if you want to edit the original data from PowerPoint, you need to Right Click the Excel object, select "Linked Binary Worksheet Object" and Edit.  I think double clicking the Excel object in PowerPoint will also open the original.  If you have edited Excel outside of PowerPoint and want to sync PowerPoint, right click on the Excel object and select "Update Link".

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I've attached an image of the menu presented to be once I right click on an Excel object from within PowerPoint.  It seems at this point this is not possible on a Mac since I do not see an "Update Link" option.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mac PowerPoint doesn't support the sort of linking that makes this simple in Windows PPT.